# Always display the full title in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a ActionBar with a logo, title, three tabs and one action item.

In portrait mode everything looks good, because the tabs is moved to the stacked ActionBar, like this:
__***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
# My title                ¤ 
_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
 Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3
__***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

But in landscape mode the title gets truncated because the tabs is moved to the top ActionBar, like this:
__***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
# My... | Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 |   ¤
__***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Is there anyway I can tell the ActionBar that the title should never be truncated? If not, can I at least set the width of the title?
(It is ok for me if the tabs gets moved to a stacked ActionBar even in landscape mode)

EDIT:

Code requested. Here it is:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = super.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.setTitle("My Long Title");

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Tab 1")
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<MyFragment>(this, "tab1",
                            MyFragment.class, null)));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Tab 2")
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<MyFragment>(this, "tab2",
                            MyFragment.class, null)));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Tab 3")
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<MyFragment>(this, "tab3",
                            MyFragment.class, null)));
}
}
```

Comment: @Anders please post the solution. If you got one

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want the fixed title then under the menu folder you will have an xml file like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <group android:id="@+id/group" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="@string/menu1"/>

        <item 
            android:id="@+id/Search"
            android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@string/menu3">
        </item>

        <item
           ..............
         </item>

    </group>

</menu>
```

In the above code **android:showAsAction** plays a vital role.If you want any item that should be shown always then you should use android:showAsAction="always".That will surely solve your problem.

I have not used SherlockFragmentActivity but i think this can help you a lot.

I suggest you to handle that through your xml file of your menu's folder with the following handling in your java file.Code is as follows:-
In your onCreate() try this:-

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_eg);//this is the xml file name inside the menu folder
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
ActionBar bar=getActionBar();
bar.show();
```

With this Changes too for your problem's Solution

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_action_bar_eg, menu);
}
```

Comment: This is not really answering the question, no? He doesn't necessary have Action Button (item). And what if all the ActionButton are already hidden, and the title is still truncate because of the Tabs?